# Selenium. Ingresar de forma directa mediante el inicio de sesion de una pagina web enviando los tokens de seguridad

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

Tengo un proyecto del cual se solicita automatizar la descarga de un reporte transaccional de registros de forma diaria, el problema es que el usuario ya esta cansado de hacerlo y necesita automatizarlo, para ello he utilizado python + selenium con la finalidad de hacerlo, el problema se da, cuando al iniciar sesión la plataforma me permite el ingreso en primera instancia, pero luego me solicita un codigo que fue enviado al correo para registrar el equipo, cuando lo hago de la forma tradicional en Chrome, el equipo se registra y cuando vuelvo a ingresar ya entra de forma directa sin que me salga ese mensaje que revise mi correo para agregar el codigo, mi pregunta es, hay manera o forma de que en la automatizacion poder enviar los cookies de seguridad para poder ingresar sin problemas, ya que cada vez que hago uso de selenium, es como que si abriera otra instancia del navegador y no la misma en la que abro de forma habitual.

Me seria de gran ayuda que me puedan indicar como hacerlo, he escuchado que se puede enviar los cookies para que el servidor detecte que es valido y lo deje pasar.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si el ambiente donde quieres realizar las pruebas es exclusivamente para la automatización, puedes solicitar al cliente que desactiven el código para que la automatización pueda pasar o se haga una expresión regular para el código que siempre sea 00000 o la otra que puedes hacer como lo sugieres es mandar los cookies con selenium.

## Navigate

```
driver.get("https://es.stackoverflow.com/")
```

## add_cookie method driver

```
driver.add_cookie({"name" : "test", "value" : "seguridad"})
```

## get browser cookie

```
driver.get_cookie("test")
```

## get all cookies in scope of session

```
print(driver.get_cookies())
```

Comment: Una consulta, cuando se agrega una cookie, hay que llamarlo para que pueda ser enviado en el inicio de sesion, o es automático? O hay forma es que en vez de abrirse una instancia nueva se abra la instancia de google chrome no automatizada, ya que alli si carga toda la data.